# Custom TableView Cell Creation with dynamic number of objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

Hello dear programmers,

I have a requirement for creating a custom tableviewcell with a method below:

```
@interface CustomTableCell : UITableViewCell {

}

@implementation CustomTableCell

-(void)setObjectWithType:(NSString *)objectType atPlace:(CGRect) placeOfObject
{
    class className=NSClassFromString(objectType);

    className *objectName = [[NSClassFromString(objectType) alloc] init];// Giving error    
}
```

Please solve this issue to create any type of object by passing the arguments like below:

```
CustomTableCell *cell=[[CustomTableCell alloc] init];
[cell setObjectWithType:@"UILabel" atPlace:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Isn't that too complicated? Why you don't create the object before the call and pass the created object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it could turn into a nightmare down the line, but to solve your immediate problem, you'd have to use `id` or the lowest common superclass (e.g. `UIView`) when creating your arbitrary objects:

```
id objectName = [[NSClassFromString....
```

The compiler can't cast dynamically the way you are attempting. It has to be done at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Use common type like `id`:

```
id objectName = [[NSClassFromString(objectType) alloc] init];
```

You can also use UIView, NSObject. depends of your purposes